# Save form data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I have a form with gender, options and user_id.
My `public function store (Request $request)` looks like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Appointment;
    $task->gender = $request->gender;
    $task->options = $request->options;
    $task->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $task->save();
}
```

This works completely fine but this is just 3 fields ?!
Eventually I want my forms 5 times bigger. My function will be huge. Is there a way to save everything with less code?

I found this : `$data = Input::all();`
This gets all the data but I don't know how to save it in the database.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature by using `create()` method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Appointment::create($request->all());
}
```

Don't forget to fill all columns in `$fillable` array in `Appointment` model:

```
protected $fillable = ['gender', 'options', 'user_id', 'another_one'];
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks! But how do I echo the data?

Comment: What data exactly do you want to echo?