# Laravel easier way to save multiple input fields to database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save a long form data to database. Till now i am getting the form value from request object and setting it to database model.
This works perfectly fine. But I want to know if there is another way to initialise the model efficiently without need to set each value. My model has one to one relation.

I have been doing like this. But i don't think this is the right way to do

```
//Student details
            $studentDetail->student_first_name = $request->input('studentFirstName');
            $studentDetail->student_last_name = $request->input('studentLastName');
            $studentDetail->student_phone_number = $request->input('studentPhoneNumber');
            $studentDetail->student_date_of_birth = $request->input('studentDOB');
            $studentDetail->student_email = $request->input('studentEmail');
            $studentDetail->save();

            $studentAddress = new Address();
            $studentAddress->address_1 = $request->input('studentAddress1');
            $studentAddress->address_2 = $request->input('studentAddress2');
            $studentAddress->city = $request->input('studentCity');
            $studentAddress->state = $request->input('studentState');
            $studentAddress->country = $request->input('studentCountry');
            $studentAddress->post_code = $request->input('studentPostCode');
            $studentDetail->addresses()->save($studentAddress);

            $visaDetails = new Visa();
            $visaDetails->passport_number = $request->input("visaPassportNumber");
            $visaDetails->visa_number = $request->input("visaVisaNumber");
            $visaDetails->visa_class = $request->input("visaVisaClass");
            $visaDetails->visa_grant_date = $request->input("visaVisaGrantDate");
            $visaDetails->visa_expiry_date = $request->input("visaVisaExpiryDate");
            $studentDetail->visaDetails()->save($visaDetails);
//
            $instituteDetails = new Institute();
            $instituteDetails->institute_name = $request->input("instituteName");
            $instituteDetails->institute_location = $request->input("instituteLocation");
            $instituteDetails->institute_phone1 = $request->input("institutePhone1");
            $instituteDetails->institute_phone2 = $request->input("institutePhone2");
            $instituteDetails->institute_email = $request->input("instituteEmail");

//            dd($instituteDetails->courses);
            $courseDetails = new Course();
            $courseDetails->course_level = $request->input("courseLevel");
            $courseDetails->course_name = $request->input("courseName");
            $courseDetails->course_fee = $request->input("courseFee");
            $courseDetails->course_concession_fee = $request->input("courseConcessionFee");
            $courseDetails->course_duration = $request->input("courseDuration");
            $courseDetails->course_commencement_date = $request->input("courseCommencementDate");
            $studentDetail->instituteDetails()->save($instituteDetails);
            $instituteDetails->courses()->save($courseDetails);
```

Any idea on making this process faster??

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436176/5454585) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34412320/5454585) to get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set create your models using mass assignment, so:

So in your model *StudentDetail*:

```
    class StudentDetail{

        protected $fillable = [
            'student_first_name',
            'student_last_name',
            'student_phone_number',
            'student_date_of_birth',
            'student_email',
        ];
        //...
        //... rest of your model
    }
```

Then tweak your HTML inputs to have in their **names** the user array like so for example:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" name="student[student_first_name]">
<input type="text" id="foo" name="student[student_last_name]">
.....
```

*Tip:* for validation, you have to treat it with dot notation, so your rule could be:

```
'student.student_first_name' => 'required|humanName|string|max:255',
```

Now simply do the following in your controller:

```
$studentDetail = StudentDetail::create($request->input('student'));
```

Now you made do the same for your *address* and other models.

**The GIST:** After mass assignment enabled for your models you could end up having **ONLY** the following couple lines of code doing it all for you and it's way more fun and full of dynamism ;) IMHO!

```
$relatedModels = ['Address', 'Visa', 'Institute', 'Course'];
    foreach ($relatedModels as $relatedModel) {
        $relatedModelClass = 'App\\'.$relatedModel; //adjust the namespace of your models here.
        $ormRelatedModel = $relatedModelClass::create(strtolower($request->input($relatedModel)));
        $studentDetail->{strtolower(str_plural($relatedModel)) . 'Details'}()->save($ormRelatedModel);
    }
```

please note that in this case your relations names should be changed a bit like `addresses` function within your StudentDetail class/model should be changed to addressesDetails or just remove the `.'Details'` from my sample code above and remove it from your other relations names, i.e: change `instituteDetails()` to `institute()`. and make the relation names plural please!

I just tested it and it's working,
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you mohammad for your answer. I a bit confused on setting one to one relation through this method. The create method sets the value directly to database. I could not attach models to each other.

Comment: You are welcome :) , and actually that I wrote you is a comprehensive solution. just please set your models/HTML to have inputs as the example. and believe me, it will buy you plenty of time ;)

Comment: to help you for the relation itself, forexanple UserDetails + Address, you should have `address_id` in your UserDetails tabe, I guess it's `user_details` then in the model `UserDetails` you should have, `public function addresses(){ return $this->belongTo(Address::class);}` please note the name of this functino should be singular! I broke the convention here just so it could fit the dynamism I have added above ;) Good luck bro!