# Store data in foreach loop in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8

I need your help with my situation in storing data.

I got a cart with several products, and now I want to store all these products in `Order` table at the same time by clicking submit button

My view blade.php

This view shows all products in the cart and I need to store these information in `Order`table

```
<form action="{{route('order.store')}}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @foreach ($cart as $ct)

  <input type="text" name="product_id" value="{{$ct->id}}" hidden>

  <input type="text" value="{{$ct->color}}" name="color" >

  <input type="text" value="{{$ct->size}}" name="size" >

  <input type="text" value="{{$ct->price}}" name="price" >

  @endforeach
 <button type="submit">submit</button>            
</form>
```

In my `Order` table, I got these 4 columns need to fill in: product_id, color, size and price.

My foreach loop gets data from `Cart` table and all data were shown without errors.

My question is that How I can store these data to my `Order` table just by click on submit button once? What I should write in my `store function` in `OrderController`?

If my cart has 3 products then my expected value is the `Order` table will look like this:

```
id----product_id----size----color---price---+
---------------------------------------------
1      1             abc     xyz     123
---------------------------------------------
2      2             abc2    xyz2    456
---------------------------------------------
3      3             aaa     bbb     789
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: This seems a bit broad.  What _specifically_ is giving you trouble?  What have you tried?  Are you doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39436176/1505169)?

Comment: I wouldn't put them in the Order table. Create a new table for the Order Items, put in all of the fields you need (order_id, product_id, color, size, price, quantity, etc), and save the items there.

Comment: I know how to store a specific product but here I want to store like 2-3 or more products at the same time

Comment: @aynber yes, but it stores only 1 product for one-click submit button and I want to store several items at the same time, I just edited my question for more specific, hope you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB:

```
Order:
    user_id
    created_at
    ...


orderProducts:
    price
    color
    size
    order_id (relation)
    product_id (relation)
    ...
```

View

```
<form action="{{route('order.store')}}" method="post">
  @csrf
  @foreach ($cart as $ct)

  <input type="text" name="products[]" value="{{$ct->product_id}}" hidden>

  <input type="text" value="{{$ct->color}}" name="color[]"  >

  <input type="text" value="{{$ct->size}}" name="size[]" >

  <input type="text" value="{{$ct->price}}" name="price[]" >

  @endforeach
 <button type="submit">submit</button>            
</form>
```

controller function store

```
        $order= new Order;// change the model here
        // .. complete your information's like user id or created_at 
        $order->save();

        foreach($request->products as $key=>$product_id)
        {
            $product = Product::findOrFail($product_id); // validations the product id 

            // get your information's from db (color,size,price) don't trust get information's from user .
            // $product->price , $product->color .... or get from cart 
           //from cart direct $color[$key] or $price[$key] or $size[$key]  "I don't recomend to use this point"


            // must be create new table
            $orderProducts=new orderProducts; // create new table ordersProducts

            $orderProducts->price = $product->price;
            // .. complete your information's

            $orderProducts->order_id = $order->id; // primary key
            $orderProducts->product_id= $product->id;

            $orderProducts->save();

        }
```

Notice:
- You need to use try-catch to record info in order if fail in the step "findOrFail" or change to find and then if product not found in the table then record order not complete and show an error to the user

Comment: I can insert multiple products at the same time, however, by this way, I can only get data from Product table, How can I get data from the cart data form?

Comment: @TùngNguyễn hmm sorry I'm don't get what you mean. Correct me if I'm wrong You need to get color and size and price direct from the cart without getting from the database?

Comment: Yes, I want to get data directly from the fields above. Although the data is available, it is changeable by users. Then when changing is made, how I can store it?

Answer (score 2):

My Answer is quite similar to above answer but i would just like to put a different approach here with Database Transaction, Try Catch & Bulk Insert(to prevent placing queries in loop)

```
try {
       DB::begintransaction();
       $order = Order::create($orderData); // change the model here


   $orderProductsData = [];
   foreach($request->products as $product_id) {
        $product = Product::find($product_id); // validations the product id
        $orderProductsData[] = $tmpData = [
            'price' => $product->price,
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'product_id' => $product->id;
        ];
        // must be create new table

        // You can also store this way, but its still in loop so putting under comment.
        // $orderProducts = orderProducts::create($tmpData); 

    }

    orderProducts::insert($orderProductsData);

  DB::commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
   DB::rollback();
   thow $e; // modify with, How you handle your error response.
}
```

Again, Above answer is totally correct, However just putting a different approach, which i believe little more optimised way.